# Overriding LLBLGen Save() with custom columns

Tags: c#, reflection, polymorphism, llblgenpro

In our program, there are about 50+ Entities in LLBLGEN. All of them have 2 columns called *ModifyDatetime* and *ModifyUserID*.  They are also the last 2 columns on each table on an SQL database.

We want to modify the LLBLGEN function of *.Save()* to have a session variable and the current time to be sent on ALL entities when the programmers do the *.Save()*

I got it to save the session user id and datetime, but I'm getting an error on some occassions and I think it has to do with the position of the column being changed at render or compile time.

I copied the 2 *public virtual* functions from one of the ___Entity.cs (in this case, it's CityEntity.cs) and it even worked when saving another entity type (ServicesEntity.cs).  So, for a while, I thought the CityFieldIndex.* was just a random int.  Both classes have different amount of columns.  Or maybe I don't fully understand this *public virtual* and how to override it.

I also tried just sending Rows.Count - 1 and Rows.Count - 2 instead of the CityFieldIndex.*

Also getting a weird error on set ModifyUserId: The value 33 is of type 'System.Int32' while the field is of type 'System.Nullable`1[System.DateTime]'
(33 is the userid)

The custom code on **CommonEntityBase.cs** is:

```
public override bool Save(IPredicate updateRestriction, bool recurse)
{
      System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("i'm overriding SAVE yeii");
      ModifyDatetime = DateTime.Now;
      ModifyUserId = 33;

      return base.Save(updateRestriction, recurse);
}

public virtual Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyDatetime
{
    get { return (Nullable<System.DateTime>)GetValue((int)CityFieldIndex.ModifyDatetime, false); }
    set { SetValue((int)CityFieldIndex.ModifyDatetime, value, true); }
}    

public virtual Nullable<System.Int32> ModifyUserId
{
    get { return (Nullable<System.Int32>)GetValue((int)CityFieldIndex.ModifyUserId, false); }
    set { SetValue((int)CityFieldIndex.ModifyUserId, value, true); }
}
```

Comment: don't have time to formulate a full answer so posting as comments. You might want to look into the [Auditing](http://www.llblgen.com/documentation/3.1/LLBLGen%20Pro%20RTF/Using%20the%20generated%20code/gencode_auditing.htm) capability built into LLBLGen itself.

Comment: also you might want to reconsider referencing HttpContext directly from Save. This ties it tightly to web application and will cause you problem if you have a console util (for example) that needs to save data. It might be better to have all the entities that support these properties implement the same interface. Then you can use the getters/setters on the entity and not have to deal with the fact that the field indexes are off.

Comment: Yes, I ran into the problem of the console util. I'm now first checking if HttpContext is null. See answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
It now saves the user from the session everytime someone else uses the Save().
If there is no user set, it just places UserId = 0.

Of course, we closed our app to verify login sessions, and only system services save using 0 :)

```
 public override bool Save(IPredicate updateRestriction, bool recurse)
    {
        ModifyDatetime = DateTime.Now;
        int userID = 0;

        // Verifies the UserId that called the Save(). Uses 0 (as system user) when none is found.
        try
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"] != null)
            { userID = Convert.ToInt32(HttpContext.Current.Session["UserID"]); }

        }
        catch (NullReferenceException nullE)
        {
            userID = 0;
        }
        ModifyUserObjectId = userID;

        return base.Save(updateRestriction, recurse);
    }

    /// <summary> The ModifyDatetime property of all Entities<br/><br/></summary>
    /// <remarks>All tables must have the field: *table*."modifyDatetime"<br/>
    public virtual Nullable<System.DateTime> ModifyDatetime
    {
    //    get { return (Nullable<System.DateTime>)GetValue((int)base.Fields["ModifyDatetime"].FieldIndex, false); }  // uncomment for GET
        set { SetValue((int)base.Fields["ModifyDatetime"].FieldIndex, value, true); }
    }

    /// <summary> The ModifyUserObjectId property of all Entities<br/><br/></summary>
    /// <remarks>All tables must have the field: *table*."modifyUser_objectID"<br/>
    public virtual Nullable<System.Int32> ModifyUserObjectId
    {
    //    get { return (Nullable<System.Int32>)GetValue((int)base.Fields["ModifyUserObjectId"].FieldIndex, false); }  // uncomment for GET
        set { SetValue((int)base.Fields["ModifyUserObjectId"].FieldIndex, value, true); }
    }
```

Still don't know if it will work for Collections. But it should be the same code.